# How to write Cayley representation permutations as cycles?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

The representation of $g \rightarrow xg$ was given to us as Cayley representation. I believe it means that every group element $g \in G$ is mapped to another element $xg$ where $x$ is the same for every element $g$. I'm not sure if $xg$ is a group but I think it is, if $x$ is also in $G$. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

How do I write these permutations in cycle notation?

Comment: Is this what your are asking about?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640077/notation-for-permutation-corresponding-to-the-action-of-a-group-element?rq=1

Comment: I think it's similar, but I'm not sure. I was looking for cycle notation, like (a b c)(d e f).

Comment: It would simply depend on the group G, and on the particular $x$ acting on the g's. So for example, for $g \in S_3$, and $x = (1, 2) \in S_3,$ then $g\to xg = (1, 2)\circ g$, where $g$ can be replaced by each and every $g\in S_3$. And yes, of course, for a given $x\in G$ $\{xg:g\in G\}$ is a group.

Comment: What if it was the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting on itself by Cayley representation?